# Sublime thTheme Scopes: Variables inside an echo

Tags: sublimetext3

In PHP, If I have the following code:

```
<?
 echo "The caption is: {$val->caption}\n";
?>
```

With sublime themes I want to change the color of the variable inside the echo.  Which is the right scope for this? And how can I find that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your cursor where you want to show the scope, then run the *Show Scope Name* command from the *Tools→Developer* menu (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have another question though, my function calls are the right color, but they are bold - how can I find out what's making it bold?

Comment: The color scheme can apply a font style of bold and/or italic to a scope along with a color, so you need to adjust the font style applied to that scope to remove the bold.